# What is the default value of G1HeapRegionSize?

Tags: java, jvm, g1gc

For the G1GC, I am trying to understand what the default value of G1HeapRegionSize argument is.

I see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F8%2Fdocs%2Ftechnotes%2Fguides%2Fvm%2Fgctuning%2F%2F/g1_gc_tuning.html) that:

> -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=n : Sets the size of a G1 region. The value will be a power of two and can range from 1 MB to 32 MB. The goal is to have around 2048 regions based on the minimum Java heap size.

But what is the value of `n` here?

Similar explanation is given [here](https://gceasy.io/gc-recommendations/important-g1-gc-arguments.jsp) too.

Comment: From the cited text “*The goal is to have around 2048 regions based on the minimum Java heap size.*” So, the default is not constant but depends on your actual minimum heap size. Consider the other cited statements “*The value will be a power of two*” and “*can range from 1 MB to 32 MB*” and you have everything you need to predict the value.

Comment: @Holger Gotchya - So basically it will try (heap size / 2048) and if it's less than 1 MB, then it will make the value of G1HeapRegionSize to 1 MB and so on

Comment: …and rounded to a power of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see default `G1HeapRegionSize` value using `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal --version | grep -i G1HeapRegionSize
```

> size_t G1HeapRegionSize = 1048576 {product} {ergonomic}

You can also specify unit using **k,m,g...** suffix. Otherwise **bits** is used. For example (Temurin 18 is being used)

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=2m --version | grep -i G1HeapRegionSize
```

> size_t G1HeapRegionSize = 2097152 {product} {command line}

G1 garbage collector partitions the heap into a set of equally sized heap regions. This parameter indicates the JVM the size of these regions. If you do not indicate this parameter to the JVM, it will use ergonomics and its magic.

More about G1 can be read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/gctuning/garbage-first-g1-garbage-collector1.html#GUID-15921907-B297-43A4-8C48-DC88035BC7CF)

Comment: I am getting this : `uintx G1HeapRegionSize                          = 0                                   {product}` as the output

Comment: So you’re not using G1GC at all?

Comment: @usuario the word is “suffix” not “subfix”. And the unit without a suffix is bytes, not bits.

Comment: @Holger - No we are using it. We have explicitly added the `+UseG1GC` arg for that.

Comment: @Mooncrater but did you also specify it when you did your `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` test?

Comment: Ohh got it. My bad.